# Swift - after saving in core data tableview is not updating

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm saving data trough this function

```
var parameter: Parameter

    if parameterToEdit == nil {
        parameter = Parameter(context:context)
    } else {
        parameter = parameterToEdit!
    }

    if let pH = phTextField.text {
        parameter.paramPH = (pH as NSString).doubleValue
    }
...........................................................
 ad.saveContext()
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

my problem is that after saving the table view is not updating.
in my tableviewcontroller i have implemented this functions:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch(type){
    case.insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break

    case.delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break

    case.update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ParamCell
            configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        }
        break
    case.move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break
    }
}
```

Not sure why is not updating.... any idea?

Comment: The delegate methods are called only if the  FetchedResultsController is initialized with the `Parameter` entity. By the way: `break` statements in `switch` expressions are not needed in Swift.

Comment: Please, add code, where you're settuping NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: i have initialized the FetchedResultsController like so: var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Parameter>! @vadian thx... i'll remove the break.. :)

Comment: I think the issue is that i'm not fetching the result in that controller... i'm passing them through a segue... is there another way to update the tableView?